# Is it possible to get an unambiguous cost summary per project?

Tags: google-cloud-billing

We have exported our billing history to bigquery. I am trying to get the total cost per project but I'm starting to think its impossible to do so because the data includes `project.labels` which means there can be multiple rows per billing item.

Here's a query I've just run:

```
SELECT   project.labels.key,project.labels.value,service.description,usage_start_time,usage_end_time,project.id,sku.description,cost 
FROM     [our-billing-export] 
WHERE    service.id = "6F81-5844-456A"
  and    usage_start_time = "2018-04-06 19:25:01.510 UTC"
  and    usage_end_time = "2018-04-06 21:25:03.785 UTC"
  and    project.id = "dh-raia"
  and    sku.id = "D973-5D65-BAB2"
order by project.labels.key,project.labels.value,service.id, usage_start_time,usage_end_time,project.id,sku.id,cost
```

which returns this:
[image]

Notice that we have 3 identical costs for "Storage PD Capacity" which I think is OK, they probably represent 3 different persistent disks. Notice also though that the same 3 costs appear again, this time for a different `project.labels.key`.

My aim is to get the total cost per `project.id`. Clearly I cannot just issue:

```
select project.id,sum(cost)
from [our-billing-export]
group by project.id
```

because some costs would be included more than once (because they appear for multiple `project.labels.key`s).

I cannot filter on a single `project.labels.key` because we do not guarantee that each project has the same labels.

I cannot try to eliminate the duplication caused by labels like so:

```
SELECT   service.id,sku.id,usage_start_time,usage_end_time, project.id,cost
FROM     [our-billing-export]
GROUP BY  service.id,sku.id ,usage_start_time,usage_end_time,project.id,cost
```

because that would eliminate the three valid line items that each have the same cost.

I cannot use the OVER() clause to obtain a single label per client like so:

```
SELECT   project.labels.key,service.id,usage_start_time,usage_end_time,project.id,sku.id,rownum
FROM     (
         SELECT   project.labels.key,service.id,usage_start_time,usage_end_time,project.id,sku.id,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project.id,service.id,usage_start_time,usage_end_time,sku.id,project.labels.key) as rownum
         FROM     [our-billing-export]
         )q
WHERE rownum=1
```

because when I do so I get error **Repeated field 'project.labels.key' as PARTITION BY key is not allowed.**

So, as far as I can tell there is no way to get a definitive answer to the question "How much have I spent on each project?" I'm hoping someone can tell me I'm wrong and that there IS a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've managed to resolve this (with some help from a colleague)

```
SELECT service.description
,      sku.description
,      project.name
,      labels
,      cost
FROM (
    SELECT  service.description
    ,       sku.description
    ,       project.name
    ,       group_concat(project.labels.key + ':' + project.labels.value) WITHIN RECORD AS labels
    ,       cost
    FROM [our-billing-export] 
    WHERE usage_start_time = "2018-04-06 19:25:01.510 UTC" 
      AND usage_end_time = "2018-04-06 21:25:03.785 UTC" 
      AND project.id = 'dh-raia' AND cost > 0
      AND sku.id = "D973-5D65-BAB2"
  )
```

Returns the correct costs 
[image]

which can then be aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

the BigQuery documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) should be useful.

Specifically, the way that a repeated field would cause double counting is if you FLATTEN that field such that other rows get duplicated. From the second link:

"Given a record with one or more values for a repeated field, FLATTEN will create multiple records, one for each value in the repeated field. All other fields selected from the record are duplicated in each new output record."

Unless you flatten the repeated fields, your simple sample query (select project.id,sum(cost) from [our-billing-export] group by project.id select) won't create double-counting issues for you.

By the way, an alternative to using Legacy SQL and the GROUP_CONCAT ... WITHIN RECORD to get the repeated field returned as a concatenated string, you could also use the TO_JSON_STRING operator in Standard SQL. See the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples#query_every_row_without_grouping).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Stephen, I'm trying to use TO_JSON_STRING like you suggest but am having trouble then extracting the value I need. Care to look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673083/jsonpath-in-bigquery-doesnt-support-for-filter-suggestions-for-alternatives